# Unable to view IP connections using netstat-nat in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, nat

I've setup NAT on an Ubuntu server (16.04) and have used TCPdump to verify that NAT works. I'm now trying to use netstat-nat to view the connections so I can quickly demo it working without resorting to packet captures. However, there seems like there is a change in Ubuntu stopping netstat-nat from working. Trace output gives:

```
strace -f netstat-nat
.
.
.
open("/proc/net/nf_conntrack", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/proc/net/ip_conntrack", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
write(1, "Could not read info about connec"..., 111Could not read info about connections from the kernel, make sure netfilter is enabled in kernel or by modules.
) = 111
```

The research I've done talks about recompiling the kernel with netfilter. Is there a way around this to get netstat-nat to work, or an alternative to netstat-nat that works?

Comment: Exactly what sort of server is this?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04. Does this answer the question? It's not "serving" anything as such. It's just a VM with IP forwarding turned on via sysctl. Forwarding works and NAT works, I just can't see the state of the NAT connections.

Comment: Does `conntrack -L` show you anything? What is the output of `virt-what`?

Comment: I had to install conntrack to get it to show me something. I see `conntrack -E -e NEW     [NEW] icmp     1 30 src=192.168.6.134 dst=192.168.6.133 type=8 code=0 id=3726 [UNREPLIED]` From the strace output it looks like something netstat-nat is looking for is missing?

Answer (score 3):

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/netstat-nat-doesnt-work-4175503334/

It seems that netstat-nat is using an old /proc file.

Update netstat-nat or use conntrack.